How to understand the Socrata FORBIDDEN 403 ERROR
It appears to be a new issue because these requests have been working for months.
The Catalog API request now suddenly shows 403 Forbidden errors.  But if we run it locally it works.  This may be an IP Rate limiting issue but the documentation says 429 should be returned.
To see a live example go to https://open.tidalforce.org/opendata/all/us/
BUT the exact same request works from the EU version of the API see https://open.tidalforce.org/opendata/all/eu/
This request even has an X-App-Token header and/or the Basic Authentication API KEY and still it receives a 403 Forbidden.
Is there anyone at Socrata or out there that can help?
The caller ip address is 35.203.245.121
Socrata Status page shows no relevant errors https://status.socrata.com/
Socrata Query is https://api.us.socrata.com/api/catalog/v1?q=&limit=100
The caller's Public IP address is: 35.203.245.121
The HTTP GET returns:
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>


Perhaps the server is down?

Thanks but no the server is working the status page shows that it's working and if you click on the link from client-side IP addresses it's working.   It appears to be some type of limit but it's not very clear what causes it maybe it's IP address.  But their documentation specifically says that it returns 429 for rate limiting.

You can go to this link and you see that it's working https://api.us.socrata.com/api/catalog/v1?q=&limit=100

It is clearly some type of IP address restriction.  Socrata has not responded so far. I've requested support.
